# VSCode Extension API: Programmatic features of custom language server are not working in a custom notebook

Tags: vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I created a language server for a custom language. If i use the built-in vscode editor, all works fine (Code completion etc.). Since my custom language is nested inside some XML-Tags i tried a custom notebook, where i de-/serialize the code part. I have the possibility to select the custom language in the notebook code cell, but programmatic features as code completion doesn't work, i always get "No suggestions"; declarative features like comments or autoclosing pairs works well. If i reopen the file with the built-in editor, everything works fine but as written before the code is inside XML-Tags and its not really user-friendly, why i have to de-/serialize it.

In the notebook i only implemented deserialize and serialize, other features like the controller or renderer i'm not using so far, because i only wanna edit code, don't have to run it inside the notebook. Are there some settings in the notebook-api to allow programmatic features? Or is someone else using a custom language server with a custom notebook and can give me maybe some hints?

An other idea i had so far was de-/serialize the file before open / before save and using the built-in editor, but i didn't try this idea until know.

Answer (score 0):

Each custom VSCode Notebook can support a number of languages. It is possible that the custom notebook is not setting the language properly for each code cell.

Each code cell's language can be identified by the language identifier in the bottom right of the cell. In the following screenshot the 'XPath' language is set for the code cell so XPath syntax-highlighting/code-completion etc. is available for that cell:

[image]

If you are not seeing your custom language identifier here then you need to use the [NotebookController API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#NotebookController): set the `NotebookController.supportedLanguages` property on an instance of `NotebookController`. This following is a sample code snippet:

```js
export class XBookController {
    readonly controllerId: string = 'xbook-id';
    readonly notebookType: NotebookType = NotebookType.xbook;
    readonly label = 'XPath Notebook';
    private readonly nodeKernel: NodeKernel;
  
    private readonly _controller: vscode.NotebookController;
    private _executionOrder = 0;
  
    constructor(type: NotebookType) {
        this._controller = vscode.notebooks.createNotebookController(
        this.controllerId = 'xpath:' + type,
        this.notebookType = type,
        this.label
      );
  
      this._controller.supportedLanguages = ['xpath'];
      ...
```